# Mount external USB drive in Single User Mode

Tags: macos, mac, usb

How can I mount an external USB drive when I'm in Single User Mode on my Mac?

I'm not able to see it in `/dev/`

Comment: Have you googled the problem?

Comment: What type of filesystem is the USB drive?

Answer (score 5):

First, get full access to your boot volume:

```
fsck -yf
mount -uw /
```

Then, get kextd and notifyd running to load the needed device drivers and create /dev/ entries:

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.notifyd.plist
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.kextd.plist
ls /dev/disk*
```

Then, to mount the volume (assuming the /dev/ entry for it is /dev/disk1s2 and it's HFS/HFS+/HFSX format; adjust as needed...):

```
mkdir /tmp/usbvolume
mount_hfs /dev/disk1s2 /tmp/usbvolume
```

Edit: at least under 10.6.4, loading notifyd and configd seems to prevent the system from shutting down normally (i.e. the `reboot` command will hang).  Loading configd and diskarbitrationd (using `launchctl load ...` as above) as well allows it to shut down normally.

Edit2: unloading kextd (`launchctl unload ...`) also allows shutdown (but you should probably wait 'till you're about to shut down).